# I'm experiencing mesh pop-in on Godot 4.0.3 web export; how do I fix this?

Tags: html5, godot, mesh, web, godot-4

I'm working on a game jam using Godot 4.0.3, and I'm intending to export to HTML5. The game works perfectly on native, but on a browser, meshes tend to pop-in when they're closer to the player than I would like. They're technically targets in a tail-gunner style game, so the earlier they can be seen, the better.

I'm also noticing that meshes with fewer vertices (~180) tend to render sooner (further away). The meshes with more vertices (~480) show up at the last possible moment. I initially assumed, given this, that it was a LOD thing, which would make sense as browsers are much more restricted environments; but I can't find a setting which reliably changes this in the final product.

To add detail, all meshes are made in Blender 3.6, and exported as blend files; some of them consist of curves and surfaces which are converted to meshes during the import, but it doesn't seem to strictly be related to that. If I un-subdivide it with a decimate modifier, the problem is mitigated quite a bit, so it still seems to be the final mesh.

To be clear, these `MeshInstance3D` nodes are created on scene load and are persistent, so it shouldn't be adding them during play time. I know now that the problem is not from creating a new node. They seem to be being culled somehow, which does not happen when I run my game native.

Is there a render setting or something that I'm missing here? Something that might make my web game more aggressively load or display the meshes? Thanks for any help.

Comment: You have found a correlation between how fast the appear and their number of vertices, however I submit to your consideration if it is the materials. If you have your shaders loading asynchronously, whatever uses them will be invisible until they load (you minimize that by reusing shaders, reusing materials, and having something that use those materials visible early - as shader loading starts when whatever uses them is on screen, not when it is on scene). About LOD, you should be able to tweak `lod_bias` on the `MeshInstance3D`, but I doubt that's the issue.

Comment: @Theraot Thank you, that's interesting. I did notice that a test mesh with two materials rendered one material before another at a distance. However, would this not mean that all meshes using the same material would appear at the same time? I had one mesh, a cinnamon stick, which would not appear until it was very close to the player until I dropped the vertex count considerably; this stick would pop in for every instance as I approached it. That said, this may be part of the problem, because baking and using textures has cut down on the issue.

Comment: @Theraot I checked out your suggestion, which I appreciate, by replacing a relatively complicated shader involving transparency with a flat white default material; unfortunately the object still popped in when uncomfortably close. I'm starting to wonder if there's some kind of node compression going on that's affected by the poly count.

Comment: Well, if loading the meshes is the problem... I don't know how much impact this makes but you could try changing their format. You said you are working with blend files, try exporting to gltf and importing that in Godot. Furthermore, converting that to Godot scene format might be better, in particular the binary one (scn instead of tscn).

Comment: @Theraot That's a great idea with the format, except that the transition to GLB happens before Godot has access. One of my most problematic models is a glb. I'm not familiar with scn instead of tscn, though. How does one go about doing that? And, are we sure that it isn't done automatically for the web?

Comment: You can open the glb in Godot as an scene, and then use save as, there you can pick tscn or scn. The tscn format is text based, while the scn is binary. I don't know if Godot does the conversion to a binary format for the web, although I believe it should. But I can tell you that changing from glb to a Godot format makes a difference.